# Python how to concatenate file names

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to include the month and year in my file name based on the month submitted.

I defined a variable that would be used to insert my file name.

```
    MTH = '20' + df['Month'].astype(str) + '/01'
    MONTH = pd.to_datetime(MTH).dt.month
    YEAR =  pd.to_datetime(MTH).dt.year
```

SAVE File Directory:

```
   df.to_excel(r'C:\OUTPUT\SALES_'+ MONTH + '_' + YEAR + '.xlsx', index=False )
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\SR\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2284, in to_excel
    formatter.write(
  File "C:\SR\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 834, in write
    writer = ExcelWriter(  # type: ignore[abstract]
  File "C:\SR\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlsxwriter.py", line 191, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\SR\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 925, in __init__
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "C:\SR\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", 
line 608, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "C:\SR\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", 
line 395, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
PS C:\SR\Desktop\Python>
```

Comment: Post the entire trace and the error and your DataFrame

Comment: I'm getting an error. `raise ValueError(msg)
 ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 
'pandas.core.series.Series`

Comment: my code is working. I just want to include month number and year in my file name

Comment: Post your DataFrame and Expected Output –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean:

```
df.to_excel(r'C:\OUTPUT\SALES_'+ MONTH.item() + '_' + YEAR.item() + '.xlsx', index=False )
```

Or:

```
df.to_excel(r'C:\OUTPUT\SALES_'+ MONTH[0] + '_' + YEAR[0] + '.xlsx', index=False )
```

Comment: I've got this error after adding .item()
`ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar`

I also tried the second one adding [0] 
`ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: @Trunks Try the second one again, copy it

Comment: thanks but still getting this error `ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: @Trunks How about `df.to_excel(r'C:\OUTPUT\SALES_'+ MONTH.tolist()[0] + '_' + YEAR.tolist()[0] + '.xlsx', index=False )`